# The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact maven + terminal

Tags: java, maven

I have executed this command from terminal:

***mvn clean package eclipse:eclipse -Declipse.pde install***

When I have executed this command i get this error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO]  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact
```

So I have decided to google it but I have not find nothing that will explain me how to solve it. In order to give you a complete overview of my problem I post also my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>example</groupId>
<artifactId>org.example.hello</artifactId>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<name>org.example.hello</name>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.example.test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <!-- External dependencies version properties -->
    <org.osgi.compendium.version>4.2.0</org.osgi.compendium.version>
    <org.osgi.core.version>4.2.0</org.osgi.core.version>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.6.2</org.slf4j.version>

    <!-- Maven plugin version properties -->
    <org.apache.felix.maven-bundle-plugin.version>2.5.4</org.apache.felix.maven-bundle-plugin.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>.</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>OSGI-INF/**</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>./src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <supportedProjectTypes>
                    <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                    <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                    <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
                </supportedProjectTypes>
                <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-ManifestVersion>2</Bundle-ManifestVersion>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>JavaSE-1.7</Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>
                    <Bundle-Vendor>Example</Bundle-Vendor>
                    <Bundle-Activator>org.example.ciao.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.slf4j;version="[1.6,2)",
                        org.osgi.framework;version="1.3",
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        org.example.ciao,
                    </Export-Package>   
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        <version>${org.osgi.compendium.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.osgi.core.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

P.S: I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LST

**Thanks for your time**

**COMPLETE ERROR**

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.forkProjectLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1205)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.forkLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1038)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:643)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact
at org.apache.maven.plugin.install.InstallMojo.execute(InstallMojo.java:136)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
... 21 more
```

**PARENT POM**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>example</groupId>
<artifactId>org.example.test</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<name>org.example.test</name>

<properties>
    <main.dir>${project.basedir}</main.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- Internal dependencies version properties -->

    <!-- External dependencies version properties -->


        <!--Felix runtime and core dependencies version properties -->

    <org.osgi.compendium.version>4.2.0</org.osgi.compendium.version>
    <org.osgi.core.version>4.2.0</org.osgi.core.version>        
    <org.slf4j.version>1.6.2</org.slf4j.version>                    

    <commons-fileupload.version>1.3.1</commons-fileupload.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
    <de.twentyeleven.skysail.org.json-osgi.version>20080701</de.twentyeleven.skysail.org.json-osgi.version>
    <org.apache.axis.version>1.4</org.apache.axis.version>
    <org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.version>2.0.4</org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.version>
    <org.apache.felix.eventadmin.version>1.4.4</org.apache.felix.eventadmin.version>
    <org.apache.felix.fileinstall.version>3.5.0</org.apache.felix.fileinstall.version>
    <org.apache.felix.gogo.command.version>0.14.0</org.apache.felix.gogo.command.version>
    <org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.version>0.16.2</org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.version>
    <org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.version>0.10.0</org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.version>
    <org.apache.felix.http.api.version>3.0.0</org.apache.felix.http.api.version>
    <org.apache.felix.http.jetty.version>3.1.0</org.apache.felix.http.jetty.version>
    <org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api.version>1.1.2</org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api.version>
    <org.apache.felix.inventory.version>1.0.0</org.apache.felix.inventory.version>
    <org.apache.felix.main.version>5.2.0</org.apache.felix.main.version>
    <org.apache.felix.org.osgi.compendium.version>1.4.0</org.apache.felix.org.osgi.compendium.version>
    <org.apache.felix.scr.version>2.0.0</org.apache.felix.scr.version>
    <org.apache.felix.useradmin.filestore.version>1.0.2</org.apache.felix.useradmin.filestore.version>
    <org.apache.felix.useradmin.version>1.0.3</org.apache.felix.useradmin.version>
    <org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds.version>2.0.0</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds.version>
    <org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.event.version>1.1.2</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.event.version>
    <org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.memoryusage.version>1.0.6</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.memoryusage.version>
    <org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.obr.version>1.0.2</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.obr.version>
    <org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.packageadmin.version>1.0.0</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.packageadmin.version>
    <org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.scriptconsole.version>1.0.0</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.scriptconsole.version>
    <org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.upnp.version>1.0.6</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.upnp.version>
    <org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.useradmin.version>1.0.2</org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.useradmin.version>
    <org.apache.felix.webconsole.version>4.2.10</org.apache.felix.webconsole.version>


    <org.restlet.osgi.version>2.1.6</org.restlet.osgi.version>
    <org.restlet.ext.servlet.version>2.1.6</org.restlet.ext.servlet.version>
    <org.restlet.ext.xml.version>2.1.6</org.restlet.ext.xml.version>        
    <org.apache.commons.httpclient.version>3.1.0</org.apache.commons.httpclient.version>
    <org.apache.commons.io.version>1.4</org.apache.commons.io.version>      
    <com.google.code.gson.version>2.2.4</com.google.code.gson.version>
    <org.apache.commons.codec.version>1.3.0</org.apache.commons.codec.version>
    <org.eclipse.jetty.version>8.1.16.v20140903</org.eclipse.jetty.version>

    <!-- Maven plugin version properties -->

    <org.apache.felix.maven-bundle-plugin.version>2.5.4</org.apache.felix.maven-bundle-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.10</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.10</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-dependency-plugin.version>


</properties>

<modules>
    <module>org.example.hello</module>
</modules>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-eclipse-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Workaround for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MECLIPSE-94 -->
            <eclipseProjectDir>..</eclipseProjectDir>
        </configuration>      
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Could you post the whole stack-trace (instead of just "BUILD ERROR")? It is interesting to know what and where it failed, what plugin is the issue, etc.

Comment: Ok. I have posted it

Comment: can you share the parent pom.xml?

Comment: Sure. I have posted it

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I just getting an error `Bundle-Activator not found on the bundle class path nor in imports: org.example.ciao.Activator`.   Can you provide a way to reproduce the issue locally?

Comment: You have this errore because you haven't add the Activator.java class in the package org.example.ciao. infact in t'ha maven bundle plugin there is the <Bundle-Activator> wwhere is specifyed the acrivator location

Comment: I understand this :) can you share some complete project to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue ?